# Hide header/footer on cover page in PDF

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 & Rails 3.2. I'm generating pdf's from html using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). 
Right now, the documents have a header and a footer, but, I'd like to show the header and footer on all of the pages **except on the first/cover page**.

This is a snipped code from my controller:

```
  render pdf: 'lorem',                                          
    page_size: 'A4',                                                            
    layout: false,                                                              
    orientation: @document.landscape ? 'Landscape' : 'Portrait',                
    encoding: 'UTF8',                                                           
    no_background: false,                                                       
    header: {html: {template: 'documents/_header'}, spacing: 35 },              
    footer: {html: {template: 'documents/_footer'}, spacing: 0 },               
    margin: {top: 30, bottom: 20, left: 0, right: 0},                           
    show_as_html: params[:html].present?
```

And this is the JS code that I tried using to hide the header:

```
function() {                                                                   
 var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');                      
 for (var i in x) {                                                           
   if(x[i] == "page=1"){                                                      
     document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";                
     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginTop = "-100px";                          
   }                                                                                               
  }                                                                           
}();
```

As you can see above, in the controller action I set the top margin to 30 (pixels, I presume?). So I'd like the top margin, the header and the footer to not be shown on the first page, but to be shown on the rest of the document pages.

Where I got stuck was when I tried to access that "middle state" of the document creation, when the JavaScript & HTML is evaluated, so, I found debugging the javascript was **very hard**.

So, is there a way to achieve the desired functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: The top margin you cannot get rid of, but I know the header and footer you can. In normal command line wkhtmltopdf you actually need to manually set them to appear on the cover, so wikced must be doing something extra to add them, you might need to contact their issue tracker directly (if they have one).

Comment: Have you tried using the `cover` option? Not sure about the margins but it will not show the header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar Header JS trick to change the header/footer for the first three pages. The same can be used to hide both elements, so they don't appear. You cannot get rid of the margin though *sob*. To get that feature, I recommend adding it as a suggestion in the wkhtmltopdf Github issue tracker.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script>
        function subst() {
        var vars = {};
        var valuePairs = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for (var i in valuePairs) {
            var valuePair = valuePairs[i].split('=', 2);
            vars[valuePair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(valuePair[1]);
        }

        var replaceClasses = [
            'frompage',
            'topage',
            'page',
            'webpage',
            'section',
            'subsection',
            'subsubsection',
        ];

        for (var i in replaceClasses) {
            var hits = document.getElementsByClassName(replaceClasses[i]);

            // Show "Hider" on pages 3 and over
            if (replaceClasses[i] == 'page' && vars[replaceClasses[i]] > 2) {
                document.getElementById('hider').style.display = "";
            } else if (replaceClasses[i] == 'page' && vars[replaceClasses[i]] == 1) {
                document.getElementById('hider2').style.display = "";
            }

            var tmp;
            for (var j = 0; j < hits.length; j++) {
                tmp = vars[replaceClasses[i]];
                if(typeof tmp !== 'undefined' && tmp) {
                    hits[j].textContent = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="subst()" style="margin: 0; padding:0;">
        <table style="width: 100%; border-top:1pt solid black;">
          <tr id="hider" style="display:none;">
            <td></td>
            <td class="" style="">FOO</td>
            <td style="text-align:right">ASDASD</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="hider2" style="display:none;">BAR</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, your solution does work, but (like you said) it doesn't remove the margins. We solved this problem by generating two documents (cover page + rest of document) and merging them into one using wkhtmltopdf and ghostscript.